# The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm, push-notification

I am sending 1000 notifications at a time, but all notifications are not sent to the device and getting this error:

> "error":{"code":"messaging/registration-token-not-registered","message":"The
> provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid
> registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons. See
> the error documentation for more details.

```
function sendPushNotification(title, token) {
       var payload = {
              notification: {
                     title: title,
                     body: title,
              }
       };

       firebase.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
              .then((response) => {
                     console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                     console.log('Error sending message:', error);
              });
}
```

Comment: so, did you `See the error documentation for more details` ? are they secret?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes